# ¿Cómo inserto una fecha en una base de datos H2?

Tags: base-de-datos, h2

mi duda es cómo insertar una fecha en una base de datos H2. Lo estoy intentando con la siguiente sentencia:

```
INSERT INTO TEMPLE VALUES (110, 121, 350, '10/11/1929', '15/02/1950', 3100, NULL, 3, 'Pons, Cesar');
```

Y me está dando el siguiente error:

> Imposible interpretar la constante "`DATE`" "`10/11/1929`"

No sé otra manera de insertar fechas, agradecería a ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos estás usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En H2 el formato de las fechas debe ser 'AAAA-MM-DD', por ejemplo '1950-02-15', o sea que tu formato es incorrecto. Solo debes intercambiar los lugares del día y el año.

Comment: Lo he conseguido, muchas gracias!!